# Sonatype Nexus: Proxy from SSL using Apache

Tags: apache, nexus, mod-proxy

We're running Sonatype's Nexus to store all of our builds, cache our dependencies, etc. etc. However, I'd like to move away from the default install's port `8081` URL and instead host it over SSL via an Apache proxy. I've setup Apache's `mod_proxy` to proxy to it such that `https://myserver.com/nexus` brings up Nexus. I used the following configuration directives inside of my virtual host config:

```
# Configure mod_proxy to be used for proxying URLs on this site to other URLs/ports on this server.
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
  AddDefaultCharset off
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

# Proxy the Sonatype Nexus OSS web application running at http://localhost:8081/nexus
<Location /nexus>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/nexus
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8081/nexus
</Location>
```

This seems to match the instructions at [Running Nexus Behind a Proxy](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html). However, I was unable to clear the "Base URL" setting in Nexus: it wouldn't let me leave it blank.

And everything *mostly* works: I can access Nexus at the HTTPS URL, log in, and perform most GUI functions.

However, when logging in I get the following warning message:

> **WARNING**: Base URL setting of `http://myserver.com/nexus` does not match your actual URL! If you're running Apache mod_proxy, here's [more information](http://links.sonatype.com/products/nexus/oss/docs-mod-proxy) on configuring Nexus with it.

And not everything in the GUI actually works. So far I've noticed the following:

- System Feeds: Gives the following error:

> Problem accessing /nexus/service/local/feeds. Reason:
>
> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request
>
> Nexus returned an error: ERROR 406: The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request
>
> Deleting Hosted Repositories: I went through and deleted several empty & unneeded repositories. However, after confirming the deletions, only the first was removed. I had to login to the `8081` site to delete any of the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to adjust the baseUrl setting in the Administration->Server configuration screen. Set the url you are using and click the Force Base Url option.

Comment: Brian: Thanks! I'd tried just setting the Base URL to the full `https` address, which hadn't worked. Enabling **Force URL** along with it, though, did the trick.

Comment: Sonatype's current documentation indicates that the original intent for the Force Base URL checkbox is no longer a valid use case, and will likely cause problems. However, the Base URL field still seems like it would be the place to make the change. http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html

Comment: Yes, forcing the baseUrl would _work_, but it would prevent other usecases. 

My usecase is I'm migrating from an old URL and need two hostnames to point to same machine.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html), it looks like a better solution may be to add a RequestHeader to the Apache configuration:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

I tried the accepted answer, which appears to work, but once I added the RequestHeader, I was able to uncheck Force URL and the warning was cleared. I have not tested the other behavior the OP is describing, though.

Comment: These should be the accepted answer !
Thanks for pointing it out, because I missed it when reading the documentation for the first time.

Comment: In nginx this would be: 

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;